# Specialized banking/credit card vocabulary

Tags: words, business-japanese

I recently found myself in a situation where I had to attempt customer service over the phone in Japanese and I got tripped up on some terminology that I've never encountered before. Most of it had to do with credit card payment logistics. Are there any good resources for dealing with this kind of specialized vocabulary?

Specifically, I found myself getting stuck on:

1. **"Charge"**, both as a verb and as a noun, in the sense of charging a certain amount to a card.

   「支払い」 seems to be an appropriate noun, but what would the verb be? 「支払わせる」 doesn't sound right to me.
2. **"Hold"**, in the sense of a temporary reservation placed on a card that will clear up by itself after a few days.

   A dictionary suggests 「数日間保留中」, but I'd like to be sure of that before I actually try using it.
3. **"Offer"**, as in "offer to buy" as a noun (e.g, "your offer" or "an outstanding offer" pertaining to an item for sale).

   I was using 「お申し込み」, but it would be nice to be more specific than this, if possible.
4. **"Finalize"**, in the sense of officially completing a transaction.

   Maybe 「纏める」? I'm not sure if that's an appropriate usage.

If you have any familiarity with this kind of vocabulary, any help would be greatly appreciated. The dictionary offers some guidance, but I'm wary of attempting to use any of these terms without seeing them in context first.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Charge

Looking at the credit card sites, お支払い　is used everywhere, with 'charge' expressed as お支払い　いただきます or お支払いは...になります. 請求 means charge, invoice so you can use it except when you yourself pay (as in 'I'll charge my credit card').

- Hold

When I was in Japan, the banking lady explained it to me with '仮’, temporary charge, temporary transfer, etc ... There might be a better way

- Offer

発売 is used for being on sale for general products, but also has a meaning/root of launching a product (from the 発 root). 売りに出す, 売り出し means put out for sale, I've heard the second one several times. The dictionary also shows 売り物, things for sale.

- Finalize

The banking term is settlement. I've heard 納める for taxes. 手続きを完成する sounds good to me, especially the 手続き sounds like a banking term, but my Japanese level is not that good. The dictionary show 決済 and 弁済 for settled payment.

Notes/remarks appreciated, my Japanese is not anywhere near native level.

Comment: 決済 is the correct word for a settled payment,  but does settled payment necessarily imply a finalized transaction? Settled payment (like of a vehicle loan)  may involve several transactions, each being "finalized". Anyway, just sounds a little ambiguous to me.

Comment: @istrasci thanks for the confirmation. The poster said he was dealing with credit card logistics and assumed he was looking for 'finalization of payment'